How to use spark configuration variables in a databricks queries?
I have my cluster configured in a way that the default catalog is defined e.g. under Spark config you find
default_catalog = dev_catalog

I checked that the table indeed exists. The following statements would return a table
%sql
SELECT * FROM dev_catalog.bronze.test_table

%python
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM dev_catalog.bronze.test_table")

Now in a notebook I can access the variable
default_catalog = spark.conf.get("default_catalog")
 --> output == dev_catalog

I now want to use it to access a table in either python or sql e.g.
%python
print(default_catalog)
spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM {default_catalog}.bronze.test_table")


After the catalog prints, I am getting a table or view not found error.
dev_catalog
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `dev_catalog`.`bronze`.`test_table` cannot be found.  Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. SQLSTATE: 42P01

In SQL
%sql
SELECT * FROM ${default_catalog}.bronze.test_table

I am getting a
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '.'. SQLSTATE: 42601

How can I correctly access the variable as set on the cluster and use it in a query?

can you run the modified python code block and post the output?

Edited the question to add the output. spark.sql("SELECT * FROM dev_catalog.bronze.test_table") returns the table if you run display() afterwards and print(default_catalog) prints dev_catalog before the error is thrown

Please try and use the IDENTIFIER clause.
Example:
-- Creation of a table using variables.
DECLARE mytab = 'tab1';
CREATE TABLE IDENTIFIER(mytab)(c1 INT);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-names-identifier-clause

Thanks for the response but it does not work with variables that are set dynamically through spark cluster config as described above. Changing your code to spark.sql(f""" DECLARE catalog = {default_catalog}; SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER(catalog).bronze.test_table """)results in the same parse syntax error.

Can you please try this way?
sql = f"""SELECT * FROM {catalog}.bronze.test_table """
spark.sql(sql)

You may be able to use parameterized queries:
spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM {dc}.bronze.test_table", dc=default_catalog)


Thanks, unfortunately that does not work as it results in a NameError as dc is not defined.
